# How to add an Android library to my project's build.gradle files (in Android Studio)?

Tags: android, import, gradle, instagram, build.gradle

I'm trying to work with Instagram in my Android app and am looking to use [this](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidInstagram): library to make things smoother; however, in trying to import the library I'm having problems. What I've done so far is to unzip the downloaded file and place its contents in my app's libs folder. The problem I'm facing is when trying to add it as a dependency in my build.gradle. So far I've tried

```
compile 'net.londatiga.android.instagram:AndroidInstagram:1.0'
```

and its various permutations (removing 'instagram', removing 'android' etc.) to no avail. Because the exact compile statement isn't listed on the github page I'm unsure as to how to import the library.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You do not import the library AND add it as a dependency. It is one or the other.

Comment: Hm, okay. Well I'm not sure how to go about either. The project's dependency isn't listed and importing the file as a module leaves my build.gradle in shambles (unable to use basic functionality such as editing).

Comment: If the third party hasn't offered a way of adding their library as a dependency then unfortunately you will have to import the library. If you receive errors after import, you are likely importing it incorrectly (as you may have guessed). Are you adding this to an existing app?

Comment: This library is not available as a Maven artifact, so you can't add it simply as a compile-time dependency. You could create a new library project in AS, copy the source files from GitHub, and add that as a dependency. But copying the sources into your app is a much easier workaround.

Comment: Yup, I'm adding this to an existing app. And @vzsg it seems adding the source files would be much easier. Do you know how exactly I could implement that? As in where I should place the source files?

Comment: @vzsg It seems copying the files into the same directory as my app's existing source files did the trick. It ought to work until I can figure out a way to properly import the library.

Answer (score 0):

I think this library should solve your problem :

https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE